# Parse iCal events using Mac OS X Automator

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, osx-elcapitan

[Here's the file I've created](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k988z81n50g7k9d/AAC0sxGpXPtKHd_W0lRZrzVta?dl=0)

[The same file uploaded to different filestorage](https://files.mycloud.com/home.php?brand=webfiles&seuuid=df7f6c26863a92415c795970d1cd9f66&name=ICAL_script__copy.workflow)

What I'm trying to do is get companies names and dates from iCal event summaries and put them into Excel file or local variable. Summaries have the following pattern:

```
$_Compamy name 11.11.2011
```

Example:

```
$_ОАО "Газпром" 11.11.2011
$_Gazprom OJSC 11.11.2011
```

My idea is to filter entries which contain `$_`, then trim last 10 characters (or extract dates from summaries).
The problem lies within Event Summary function of the automator, which generates too much odd text like this one:

```
TOTAL EVENTS: 3

EVENT 1 OF 3
Summary:    $_Gazprom OJSC 11.11.2011
Status: none
Date:   10/6/15 to 10/6/15
Time:   9:00:00 AM to 10:00:00 AM
```

I need to build names list and dates list separately in order to use them for document filling, but I can't figure out how to grab specific text for all the events in calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of the summary strings, without all of the odd text, you will need to utilize AppleScript, either as a standalone script, or within a **Run AppleScript** Action inside of Automator.  Here is some general code that will create a list of just the summaries of a week's worth of dates in a specific Calendar, with some explanations in the comments:

```
--This section just defines a pair of dates to search within the Calendar
set rightNow to current date --Today
set rightNow's time to 0 --Set the time to the beginning of the day
set oneWeek to rightNow + (days * 7) --Add 7 days to get a week of Events

set eventSummaries to {} --Define an empty list to hold all of the Event Summaries
tell application "Calendar"
    set thisCalendar to item 1 of (get every calendar whose name is "Craig") -- Identify the Calendar to pull the Events from
    set theseEvents to every event of thisCalendar whose start date is greater than rightNow and start date is less than oneWeek -- Get the Events
    repeat with eachEvent in theseEvents
        set end of eventSummaries to eachEvent's summary -- Add each Event's Summary to the empty list
    end repeat
end tell
```

Good luck,